# How to deduplicate Virtualbox VMs

Tags: virtualbox, deduplication

I'm generally creating a new clone of my existing VM with "linked clone" option to save space. However, for some reasons (backup/restore etc.), I end up with fully cloned machines thus using huge spaces on the disk.

Is there any way to deduplicate the shared portions of VirtualBox VMs' data?

Comment: Not sure this is the solution, but you can create a state of the virtual machine, and use that as separate machine. This creates a separate file. You can backup that file.

Comment: I might not express my intention well: Say I have a 5GB VM. I created 4 "linked clone"s and installed 100MB data each of them. I'll end up with raughly 5.4GB disk space usage. Then I backed up one of the clones (via `.ova` file of VB) and removed it. Then I re-inserted that backup to the VB registry. Now I'm using 5.3GB (1 base, 3 clones) + 5.1GB (1 full clone) = 10.4GB of disk space. How can I deduplicate the data so that I end up using 5.4GB again instead of 10.4GB?

Comment: Not sure, I think you must backup everything and restore everything to keep that in tact.